# help with count with left join

Tags: mysql, count

I have 2 tables

- 1st table called *services* has *id_service*, *name*, *date*.
- 2nd table called *services_images* has *id_img*, *img_name*, *id_service*.

What I wanna do is get list of services with a row called *num_images* that counts how many images there are per service.

I tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(services_images.id_img) as num_images, services.* FROM services
LEFT JOIN services_images ON (services_images.id_service = services.id_service) ORDER BY service.id_service
```

It doesnt work and I dont know how to fix it. This will return just ONE service (the first id_service: 1) with as num_images the count of all the rows in *services_images*! Even if change "`services_images.id_service = services.id_service`" to "`services_images.id_service = 2`" it stills shows the first ID! So this rules is not even considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a GROUP BY clause should do the trick

```
SELECT COUNT(services_images.id_img) as num_images, services.* 
FROM services
LEFT JOIN services_images ON (services_images.id_service = services.id_service) 
GROUP BY service.id_service
ORDER BY service.id_service
```

This will group your rows by service and the count aggregation will give you the count of images per service.